# Getting error during creating rails app -> ruby/2.3.0/erb.rb:864:in `eval': (erb):4: syntax error, unexpected '=' (SyntaxError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, osx-elcapitan

I'm newbie to Ruby on Rails. I complete installation with little to no stress, but while create a new app using command 'rails new ' I'm getting error and /bin is not getting generated. Error log below. I've spent whole night trying to understand the cause but alas with no success. Any help will be appreciated.

Few details of my machine :
I'm using OS X El cap v 10.11.5

Rails on 4.2.6
Ruby on 2.3.1

database is Mongodb enterprise 3.2.7

error details

```
localhost:versions kiranchakravarthy$ rails --version
Rails 4.2.6
localhost:versions kiranchakravarthy$ rails _4.2.6_ new hello_world
      create  
      create  README.rdoc
      create  Rakefile
      create  config.ru
      create  .gitignore
      create  Gemfile
/Users/kiranchakravarthy/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/erb.rb:864:in `eval': (erb):4: syntax error, unexpected '=' (SyntaxError)
 = gem.comment 
  ^
(erb):6: syntax error, unexpected '=', expecting keyword_end
 = gem.commented_out ? '# ' : '...
  ^
    from /Users/kiranchakravarthy/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/erb.rb:864:in `result'
    from /Users/kiranchakravarthy/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/actions/file_manipulation.rb:116:in `block in template'
    from /Users/kiranchakravarthy/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/actions/create_file.rb:53:in `render'
    from /Users/kiranchakravarthy/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/actions/create_file.rb:62:in `block (2 levels) in invoke!'
    from /Users/kiranchakravarthy/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/actions/create_file.rb:62:in `open'
    from /Users/kiranchakravarthy/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/actions/create_file.rb:62:in `block in invoke!'
    from /Users/kiranchakravarthy/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/actions/empty_directory.rb:116:in `invoke_with_conflict_check'
    from /Users/kiranchakravarthy/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/actions/create_file.rb:60:in `invoke!'
    from /Users/kiranchakravarthy/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/actions.rb:94:in `action'
    from /Users/kiranchakravarthy/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/actions/create_file.rb:25:in `create_file'
    from /Users/kiranchakravarthy/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/actions/file_manipulation.rb:115:in `template'
    from /Users/kiranchakravarthy/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/generators/rails/app/app_generator.rb:17:in `template'
    from /Users/kiranchakravarthy/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/generators/rails/app/app_generator.rb:45:in `gemfile'
    from /Users/kiranchakravarthy/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/generators/app_base.rb:132:in `build'
    from /Users/kiranchakravarthy/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/generators/rails/app/app_generator.rb:186:in `create_root_files'
    from /Users/kiranchakravarthy/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
    from /Users/kiranchakravarthy/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `invoke_command'
    from /Users/kiranchakravarthy/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:133:in `block in invoke_all'
    from /Users/kiranchakravarthy/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:133:in `each'
    from /Users/kiranchakravarthy/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:133:in `map'
    from /Users/kiranchakravarthy/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:133:in `invoke_all'
    from /Users/kiranchakravarthy/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/group.rb:232:in `dispatch'
    from /Users/kiranchakravarthy/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/base.rb:440:in `start'
    from /Users/kiranchakravarthy/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands/application.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/kiranchakravarthy/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /Users/kiranchakravarthy/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /Users/kiranchakravarthy/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/cli.rb:14:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/kiranchakravarthy/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /Users/kiranchakravarthy/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /Users/kiranchakravarthy/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/kiranchakravarthy/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/bin/rails:22:in `load'
    from /Users/kiranchakravarthy/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/bin/rails:22:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try reinstalling Ruby 2.3.1 via your rbenv